# Windows 8 hangs up on splash screen

Tags: windows-8.1

I feel kind of silly asking this question, but here goes...

I'm visiting my sister-in-law and don't have access to any of my ordinary tools (external floppy, external DVD drive, etc.) and her laptop hangs on the Windows 8 splash screen, and the touchpad and keyboard don't work. All we see is the clock (which does change as time passes) and the wifi and battery level icons. The keyboard does have its illumination under the keys.

I have tried a complete power down (using the power button), but that didn't work--neither short press/sleep nor long press/shut down.

The computer is a Toshiba Satellite E55-a5114, with Windows 8.1. No DVD drive, but several USB drives and an SD card slot.

I haven't worked with Windows 8, but from other sites I've read, there is no F8 access to Safety Mode any more.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: "Press and hold down the 0 (zero) key on the keyboard while powering on the computer/tablet.  Release it when the recovery warning screen appears." This should get you started. Hoping you get shown some type of repair option.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I was able to 'Refresh' the laptop and it's now working.